# xcode 9 extra padding above uitableview after just dragged from view controller panel , storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

Before updating to Xcode 9.0 , I use Xcode 8.3.3 to work on uitableviewcontroller. There has first row explicit large . After upgrading to Xcode 9.0, it occurs. Even though I cancel [image]automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets , the padding is still here. Hass anyone ever encountered to this issue ? How to resolve it ? 
[image]

[image]

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    let btn1 = UIButton(type: .custom)
    btn1.setImage(UIImage(named: "add"), for: .normal)
    btn1.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
    btn1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(createStaff(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    let item1 = UIBarButtonItem(customView: btn1)

    let btn2 = UIButton(type: .custom)
    btn2.setImage(UIImage(named: "back_arrow"), for: .normal)
    btn2.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
    btn2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(back(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    let item2 = UIBarButtonItem(customView: btn2)

    self.navigationItem.setRightBarButton(item1, animated: true)
    self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButton(item2, animated: true)
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false;


    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.init(rawValue: 0)

 }
```

[image: I HAVE EVEN TICKED SAFE LAYOUT BUT TO NO AVAIL]

Comment: I think you might be experiencing the safe area - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44492404/safe-area-of-xcode-9-beta

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: I only drag out the uitableview and there has no safe area for me to drag.

Comment: It would be helpful if we could see what you are talking about - please post screenshots of your storyboard and the app running

Comment: app screenshots updated . What else I have to upload ?

Comment: Are you implementing the `UITableViewDelegate` method called `tableView(_:heightForRowAt:)`?

Comment: Not really. Interestingly , when i tick and untick safe area layout, the Xcode hangs and limit my edit . I have just sent the bug report to Apple

Answer (score 0):

write the following line in viewdidLoad -

```
  self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false;
```

and remove the last line

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.init(rawValue: 0)
```

Hope it helps...