# iPhone X Custom Navigation Not Showing Properly

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I used [AMScrollingNavbar](https://github.com/andreamazz/AMScrollingNavbar), and customize it,  it works perfectly on all devices but behave differently in iPhone X.
[image]

Comment: Try detecting when Device is iPhone X , Do something Different for it Like some different Constraints

Comment: @iOSGeek i did not used any constraints in bar items,

Comment: Hello Ayaz ,
you should use safe auto layout guide .follow the instruction by visit pasted link.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44492404/safe-area-of-xcode-9

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Safe Area of Xcode 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44492404/safe-area-of-xcode-9)

Answer (score 0):

Add a LaunchImage Image of size **1125px × 2436px**  in Portrait Mode &     **2436px × 1125px** in Landscape Mode in Assets.

It will fix the issue of Black Area, while it will create a gap of 20 pixels, which you fix by setting Constraints.

Reference

https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/launch-screen/