# UITableViewController SafeAreaLayout for Top & Bottom

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, ios11, iphone-x

I have added `UITableViewController` in `storyboard`. This `UITableView` merges with the home indicator on an `iPhoneX` device and on top also cut.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Put screenshot here so get better ideas.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44492404/safe-area-of-xcode-9

Comment: @NKmewara I have alredy checked this but i am not able to update in tableviewcontroller

Comment: @NimishaRanipa i m posting a image in answer section

Comment: @NimishaRanipa have you solved this?

Answer (score 2):

select your main viewController or your main view in storyboard and enable the option safe area layout Guide

[image: check in this image]

Comment: I already configure like this. 

Because in my case its TableViewController not UIViewController.

Comment: @NimishaRanipa ok i will create a example for you.

Comment: @NimishaRanipa https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JYME4ooG9Yg check it and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4RyhnwIRjpA

Answer (score -1):

use this:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
        tableView.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    }
```