# White status bar when hide tab bar

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have a custom `UITabBarController` and I found this code a long time ago to animated hide tab bar when I press some button. This works very well until upgrade to **iOS 11** and now the status bar turns white when tab bar is hidden.

I can't figure out what happened. It's like *Y* position of view increase 20 points, below the status bar and code:

[image]

```
extension CustomTabBarController {

    func showTabBar(_ notification: Foundation.Notification) {
        setTabBarVisible(true, animated: true)
    }

    func hideTabBar(_ notification: Foundation.Notification) {
        setTabBarVisible(false, animated: true)
    }

    fileprivate func setTabBarVisible(_ visible: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        let frame = tabBar.frame
        let height = frame.size.height
        let offsetY = (visible ? -height : height)
        let duration: TimeInterval = (animated ? 0.3 : 0.0)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration) {
            self.tabBar.frame = frame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: offsetY)
            self.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height + offsetY)
            self.view.setNeedsDisplay()
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I noticed the same issue on my iPhone 6s Plus. I originally was running iOS 11.0.2 and it seemed to work properly. After updating to iOS 11.1.2, it has the issue. This leads me to believe it was introduced after 11.1.

**Solution:** Removing this line seemed to give me the results that I expected.

```
self.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height + offsetY)
```

Hope this helps

`- Amir`

Comment: Found this as well. Not sure if you've figured it out or not but might be helpful to others. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44492404/safe-area-of-xcode-9/45334411#45334411