# How to make datePicker generated by textField not cover iPhone X home indicator

Tags: ios, datepicker

my datePicker was generated by textField(let the textField.inputView = myDatePicker). However the datePicker cover the home indicator. How to adjust it up, just like the keyboard does?
Since I am newbie and do not understand the other way to activate datePicker, so what is a better way to do this? any help is appreciated.

[image: datePicker covers home indicator]

[image: the ideal way to show]

Comment: Code you've tried?

Comment: Is `Safe Area Layout Guides` enabled for your view controller? See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45334411/3411787)

Comment: I face same issues in iphone x, Safe Area Layout Guides is enable in view controller.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue did anyone solved it. If someone solved it then kindly share the fix as an answer to this problem.