# UIPageControl for Walkthrough

Tags: uikit, uipagecontrol, iphone-x

I have previously used [MyBlurIntroductionView](https://github.com/MatthewYork/MYBlurIntroductionView) library for presenting walkthroughs of my app but the problem is it is buggy on iPhone X -- the content gets cut off by the notch on iPhone X. The library has not been updated for years so I need something that works on iPhone X. I am not sure if it a problem with setup of UIPageControl. Any inputs to fix it or an alternative library that is better for presenting walk through tutorials on iOS?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly on [MYBlurIntroductionView](https://github.com/MatthewYork/MYBlurIntroductionView), Launch screen is missing add it by

> Xcode-> NewFile-> LaunchScren

Assign it on your target

[image]
**Output**

[image]

> Since MyBlurIntroductionView is very old source project you have to provide constraints
>   with respective to safe area([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46665609/7576100))