# UI Difference in IOS 11 and Lower versions

Tags: ios, user-interface, ios11.2

In my application while designing the UI i am facing some UI Issue.
The `Top contraints` I am setting in story board are coming same in `IOS 11` but in versions lower to that UI is moving up. Please see the attached image

[image]

As you can see image in `IOS 10` is above from the one in `IOS 11.2`. 
How I can have the same UI in all the versions. 
Contraints I have added are below:

[image]

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please include the constraints you're using.

Comment: Did you enable [SafeAreaLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44492404/safe-area-of-xcode-9)?

Comment: Yes it is enabled. Whatever UI i have set in storyboard is coming as it is in IOS 11 but there is a lot of difference in ios 10

Comment: I dont get this weird contentInsets, safeArea stuff either.. I cant find a good way to target ios 9 to 11 either as apple keeps changing it

Comment: @Daij-Djan same here. Either we have to disable the safe area which is again not the good approach. I need a proper solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding below line in my view controller solved my problem.

```
edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.init(rawValue: 0)
```

It appears that in `iOS 10` and below my view was going under the navigation bar which made to look that view has shifted up. But it was working all fine in `iOS 11`. So to avoid view controller to go behind any bars added the above line which solved my problem.