# UITableViewController top bar on iPhone x

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, iphone-x, safearealayoutguide

I found problem with one of my app's screens UITableViewController on iPhone X. I am talking about color of top bar.

Other screens in app are presented as UIViewControllers where I have no problem with safe area setting background to be till the top.

What should be done for UITableViewController? Maybe it can be done in interface builder?

[image]

I tried this with no luck

```
self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
```

Comment: self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/45334411/3515115

Answer (score 0):

- Select ViewController
- Go to "File Inspector"
- Uncheck the Box "Use Save Area Layout Guide"