# UITabBarController on iPhone X

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, iphone-x, safearealayoutguide

This is not a duplicate. 
All the other answers are for use of `UITabBar` in a `UIViewController`. My question is specific to `UITabBarController` and those answers did not help. My tabbar works great on other simulators but on iPhone X (11.2) as you can see in the attached image, the icons and text are overlapping.

- My `UITabBarController` is custom but I have also tried removing the customization and this problem persists.
- My storyboard has "Use Safe Area Layout Guides" turned on
- My `UITabBarController` does not show safe area in the storyboard.

I have exhausted all solution on stack related to this.

[image]

Comment: duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44492404/safe-area-of-xcode-9

Comment: @rMickeyD how does it answer my question? It is a general discussion of safe areas. My question is a specific problem.

Comment: There could be any number of reasons for this. You'll need to provide more information than just a screenshot.

Comment: I am also experiencing this issue. Have you been able to figure anything out Kashif?

Comment: Yes i checked if i was on iPhone X and changed tab bar height to 100.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix this problem by checking if the device is iPhone X and setting the `UITabbar` height to 100 points.

Comment: This is not a generic solution