# Can iPhone SE design work for iPhone X

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone-x

I have designed my app without auto layout and for the size 320*568 (iPhone SE). The design i did for iPhone SE itself worked up to iPhone 7plus bcoz of adding corresponding launch image. Even it now works for iPhone 8 plus. But for iPhone X, it doesn't seem to be appearing full screen(Pl find the below image). Is there a quick fix or do i have to use autolayout to get it right?[image]

Comment: Use [Safe Area Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44492404/safe-area-of-xcode-9/45334411#45334411) - Show your design issue (snapshot)

Comment: @Krunal Please check the design issue. It does not appear full screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Autolayout is the best for the iOS design to make it responsive according to the different device, so it is suggested to use autolayout. There are some reasons for why we should use the autolayout ?

1. It assures that it looks fine on all the devices.
2. It requires less effort to make design responsive if you are looking for different sizes or orientation.
3. It is easy to update the design when there is new device introduced.

And for particularly your question. If you want great design on all the device including iPhone X you should use 'Safe Area' + 'Autolayout'.