# iphone 10 design issue with auto resize

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, autoresize, iphone-x

I am developing an iOS app.I am using auto resize(not auto layout) for designing view.But my deisgn is suitable for iphone 10.It looks stretched.Please guide me to deisgn using auto resize.iphone 10 will only support autolayout?Please refer my screenshots [iphone10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQFqp.png) ,[iphone5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mW00q.png).In xib iteself,while i am changing iphone-X it looks like this

Comment: You need to provide some screenshots of your design/IB because we can't help you with this amount of informations.

Comment: It looks stretched ..? is not clear

Comment: add some info for e.g ui or code else something

Comment: @Anbu.karthik I have added screens.Please refer that

Comment: @Madhu Uncheck height from autoresize for `imageView`. Also use contentMode `aspectFit`.

Comment: @Madhu - check the answer

Comment: `Safe Area Layout` is best option to design with iPhone-X. Use [Safe Area of Xcode 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44492404/safe-area-of-xcode-9/45334411#45334411)

Answer (score 0):

In `Autoresizing` you should do like below picture:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like autoresizing is not keeping aspect ratio in iPhone X and newer. So that layout based on autoresizing doesn't look good anymore on these new models.

The workaround I'm using is specifying the aspect ratio I want manually. For example if I want the circular label to stay circular on all devices, instead of turning into elipse, I adjust hight to be equal width manually:

```
self.frame.size.height = self.frame.size.width
```