# How to use Safe Area Layout Guide without Autolayout?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, autolayout, safearealayoutguide

I would like to compact my iOS app also in iPhone X. This iOS app developed using autoresizing and deployment target is iOS8.
I had chosen my **viewcontroller** in storyboard.Then I tried to check **Use Safe Area Layout Guide** but it automatically appear check mark on **Autolayout**.Please go through the image.I want to compact iPhone X design of my app without autolayout.How to solve this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> You can't use `Safe Area Layout` without `Auto Layout`

Look at this Apple Document: 

[safeAreaLayoutGuide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/2891102-safearealayoutguide) is member/instance of [UILayoutGuide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilayoutguide) class.
And [UILayoutGuide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilayoutguide): is a rectangular area that can interact with **Auto Layout**.

So, you must enable auto layout if you want to use Safe Area Insets.

I think, there is no way.

Here is more detail about [Safe Area of Xcode 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44492404/safe-area-of-xcode-9/45334411#45334411)

Comment: My app already developed using autoresizing,then how to achieve iPhone X compactable ?

Comment: You either need to write a bunch of code that lays out everything out based on the size of the screen or bite the bullet and adopt autolayout.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have faced same situation where my old app which was made with Auto Resize thing and need to update with make it compatible for iPhone X, so what I had done so far is to adding splash screen for iPhone X, the following image will give you an idea to how to do this.

[image]

After doing that my app now compatible with iPhone X and i have to have add some new condition where design got disrupted. You can try this. hopefully it may help you.

Thanks