# Extra white space shows up in my UIViewController

Tags: swift, uiview

I've no idea why is this happening. I already deleted the view controller and try new.. It's being the same. In following pic, the dark grey view's constraints are all zero.

[image]

When I run this.., it appears.

[image]

That ViewController is embedded in navigation controller which is connecting tab view controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unselect Adjust scroll view Insets.

[image]

Also,try in option 'Extend Edges' and uncheck the 'Under Top Bars'

Comment: Nothing is changed.

Comment: Edited my answer Also,try in option 'Extend Edges' and uncheck the 'Under Top Bars'

Answer (score 1):

Just Set Constraints to 0  due to SafeArea, the `IB` automatically handle `SubViews` in your case i can see that is not to `safeArea` constraint `safeArea` is 20pt height only you can even drag the View manually to above the `safeArea`.

If you can't see `SafeArea` you can enable it by clicking on the `UIViewController` on the right menu top items click on show file inspector and this will show up just enable use Safe Area Layout Guides.

Read about `safeArea` [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45334411/8192960)

[image: IB]