# Putting the navigation bar to be under the status bar

Tags: iphone, swift, statusbar, navigationbar, xcode-storyboard

[image: iphonex]

Hi, wanted to put the navigation bar to be cleared of the status bar but somehow could not figure it out.  Now part of the back and the title are covered under the status bar.

I have only used a standard way of presenting the view controller:

```
let main = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let leaveListView = main.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LeaveListView") as! LeaveListViewController
 present(leaveListView, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Is there a way to change the settings through storyboard?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you have to work with safe area.

Comment: @A.H.Nuri, where can I set that in storyboard?

Comment: Please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44492404/safe-area-of-xcode-9

Comment: In iphone 8 plus, it is perfectly ok

Comment: iPhone 8 doesn't have notch. To make compatible for all devices you need to add Safe Area in your project.

Comment: @DarylWong Please share your storyboard screenshots along with constraints

Comment: yes, it is related to the constraint.  I just have to constraint the top of the navigation bar to the safe area and it resolves the issue.  The navigation bar can now be view correctly in iphone xr and iphone 8 plus.