# Iphone XR navigation bar height

Tags: iphone, iphone-xr

My application works fine with all devices but for iphone Xr and Xs Max Navigation bar is half visible. While I take screen shot it looks fine but in simulator it looks like this. I am not having a real device(iphone Xr and Xs Max). Can any one guide, what should I do!

[image]

Comment: Are you using storyboard or programatically you created the views?

Comment: I am using storyboard

Comment: I think you gave your view top constraint to superview, so change your constraint to safearea then check

Comment: The top and bottom constraint should be change superview to safe area.

Comment: For more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44492404/safe-area-of-xcode-9

Comment: @FaysalAhmed but my screen looks fine with IphoneXS and iphone X !

Comment: Have you tested in a real device?

Comment: @FaysalAhmed for Iphone XS i have tested with real device.