# status bar overlay ios real device (iphone X)

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, iphone-x

I have submitted for review update for my xamarin.ios app. Review team declined my app due to " Your app was not optimized to support the iPhone X and later device screen size or resolution. The iOS status bar overlapped the app’s UI elements." (screen below)

[image]

But I can't reproduce this error on simulator. It seems ok on virtual device (screen below).
[image]

This error appeared after updating Visual Studio 2019 and I have no idea how to debug and fix this error.

Comment: the first image isn't iPhone X?

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable safe area inset for supporting notch devices like iPhone X, XR, XS and 11. try this code :

```
using Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration;
using Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;
...

On<iOS>().SetUseSafeArea(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a try with setting **safeArea** to check whether it works.

About **Xamarin.iOS** could refer to **[safeAreaLayoutGuide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/2891102-safearealayoutguide)** from Apple document, then there is [another similar discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44492404/safe-area-of-xcode-9#:%7E:text=To%20use%20the%20new%20safe,the%20overscan%20region%20on%20tvOS.) about navitve iOS how to achieve that, you also can refer to do the same in Xamarin.iOS.

Here is the **Xamarin.iOS** sample code for reference:

```
public override void ViewDidAppear(bool animated)
{
    base.ViewDidAppear(animated);
    
    //suberView is your subview view in ViewController
    View.Add(suberView);
    suberView.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;

    var safeGuide = View.SafeAreaLayoutGuide;
    suberView.LeadingAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(safeGuide.LeadingAnchor).Active = true;
    suberView.TrailingAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(safeGuide.TrailingAnchor).Active = true;
    suberView.TopAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(safeGuide.TopAnchor).Active = true;
    suberView.BottomAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(safeGuide.BottomAnchor).Active = true;

    View.LayoutIfNeeded();
}
```